# How to execute 3 Commands (SQL statements) to 3 different Oracle tables at one shot?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm implementing an application using vb.net 2005 with Oracle 10g and I came across a functionality that should Select/Insert/Update/Delete data from three different tables in Oracle.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to prepare all the 3 commands (SQL Statements) separately and then execute them in one shot to the oracle, so in this way I can guarantee that all of them are successfully executed or all are failed to execute, and also I could gain more performance which is critical in my case.

Thus I'm looking for a syntax in vb.net that helps me execute more than one OracleCommand in one shot to the oracle.

Comment: You need to check out transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be answered with a pseudocode

```
Dim cnn as OracleConnection
Dim tr as OracleTransaction 
Try
    cnn = new OracleConnection("your_connection_string")
    cnn.Open()
    tr = cnn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)

    Dim cmd1 as OracleCommand = con.CreateCommand();
    Dim cmd2 as OracleCommand = con.CreateCommand();
    Dim cmd3 as OracleCommand = con.CreateCommand();

    cmd1.CommandText = "Your_Query_Text1"
    cmd2.CommandText = "Your_Query_Text2"
    cmd3.CommandText = "Your_Query_Text3"    

    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()

    tr.Commit()
    cnn.Close()
    cnn = Nothing
    tr = Nothing
Catch
   if tr <> Nothing then
       tr.Rollback()
   End if 
   If cnn <> Nothing Then 
       cnn.Close()
   End If
   cnn = Nothing
   tr = Nothing
End Try
```

A transaction makes the database perform a series of actions as a unit. You mark the start of a transaction calling the BeginTransaction method of your connection. Operations inside a transaction block are guaranteed to either all occur or all not occur.

If everything goes well, you confirm the transaction and everything is persisted in your tables. If something happens to interrupt your code flow (exceptions) you should call "rollback" to cancel everything you have done to the database while inside the transaction.

Comment: Thank you Steve...I just want to know if your way can provide me better performance from doing each command alone..or just it rollback the execution in case of error...please advise...

Comment: Also I wanna tell you to remove the 3 lines cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery() because Transaction property of OracleCommand is ReadOnly and can`t be assigned...

Comment: @Davideg Do you mean the three line where I assign the transaction to the command?. Yes, you are right. If you use the ODP.NET that property cannot be set. Also the client from Microsoft has some hiccups with that. I will try to edit the answer

Comment: @Davideg Cannot give a strong advice on performance without knowing the query text. However, in similar situations, the best improvement can be achieved looking at a storedprocedure that execute, in a single call, all of your related commands.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use the storedprocedure to execute all my commands in one call...And bear in mind that I`m inserting/selecting BLOB datatypes with my commands...

Comment: @Davideg sorry, but this is really a broad subject that cannot be resumed in a comment here. However if you search the Internet with keywords like "ODP.NET calling stored procedure" you will find numerous articles worth to read. For example [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28844/procedures_plsql.htm) (Really, all the docs on that site should be your starting point).